# Migrating a C++ project from VS 2005 to VS 2015- Unable to create dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, migration, visual-studio-2005

Hi I am migrating a C++ project from VS 2005 to VS 2015. But unable to create the dll. On building the project I get the error cannot open .dll file. The project references another library too, and when I open that project and tried to build the project failed and I see there are many syntax errors in the .h files and I am not able to open .cpp files in that library project! Do I need to successfully build the referred library for building my project? Am I right or is there a right solution for this issue.

Comment: You should rebuild all the necessary DLLs, otherwise it probably [won't work](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150911-00/?p=91611).

Comment: Do you mean the library ?

Comment: Yes especially static libraries.